# Cleaning up the "logo" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't yet have the editing rights, and there are a lot of posts incorrectly using the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag.

Just wanted to give you a heads up.

I am just removing the tag, in almost all of the questions there are already plenty of tags on the questions and a [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) isn't needed to make the question make sense.

Comment: Logo is a programming language. If posts are using it incorrectly, why not suggest edits that clean these up? Make sure that you clean up all problems with a post you edit.

Comment: I like that you made a new tag for the kind of logos they are using. that makes sense

Comment: I've been cleaning up the tag, but I am out of time. Not much left to do though.

Comment: I see that, there was quite a few that were grossly misusing that tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just having reviewed some of your suggested edits, I have approved them all so far. (And you have done well in editing other stuff in the questions as well)

Seems like people think that [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) is related to the logo of your company, or the logo of your application. So you're right. It is being horribly mis-used. Perhaps it should have been named as [logo-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-language), although as it currently stands it is probably better to just tag the existing questions correctly.

#### [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) is about the language, not what kind of image you're working with!

Comment: if you read the [tag:logo] wiki it now says why they left the [tag:logo] the way it is

Comment: @MartijnPieters made a new tag [tag:graphical-logo]

Comment: @Malachi: I did not create a new tag; it existed already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh cool, I didn't know that. lol

Comment: +1 for `logo-language`. I know that this is a programming site, as the authors of the wiki maintain, but that doesn't mean we have to be stupid about our tag (variable) names.