# Proposal to rename "logo" tag to "logo-language"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

About half-a-year ago, the following question was asked here about the health of the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag:

- [Cleaning up the "logo" tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259982/cleaning-up-the-logo-tag)

At that time, the concern was that many questions regarding graphical logos were inappropriately using the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag (which is meant to reference the language).  The solution at the time was to create a new tag called [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo) and then manually edit all of the offending questions to reference that new tag.  The wikis for the two tags were updated to make the intentions explicitly clear.

The hope was that people asking new questions about graphical logos would see the new tag and use it instead.  It was suggested, at the time, that the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag could be renamed to [logo-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-language) just to avoid future accidental use, but the community decided not to go that far.  We took the principled stance that Logo is a legitimate programming language and therefore deserves its own self-named tag and people should just be smart enough to not use it for graphical-logos (especially when a dedicated [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo) tag exists).  The following explanation was even added to the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag wiki:

> The rationale behind reserving [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) for the programming language (and relegating corporate logos to the [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo) tag) is that this is a *programming* site.

I agree in principle with that decision, but I contend that in practicality, it's not working.  I have recently taken up the cause of keeping the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag clean, but it's getting a bit exasperating.  There's typically only about one legitimate logo-language question per month, but there is a new graphical-logo question practically every day.  Here's a list of the most recent examples, just in case anyone is curious:

- February 4, 2015 - [Show logo then hide it to show favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321348/show-logo-then-hide-it-to-show-favicon)
- February 4, 2015 - [How to change app name with an image, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322439/how-to-change-app-name-with-an-image-android)
- February 3, 2015 - [Logotype in SVG - pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298248/logotype-in-svg-pros-and-cons)
- February 3, 2015 - [Size retina text logo photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284293/size-retina-text-logo-photoshop)
- February 2, 2015 - [Logo change of my magento rwd theme which is showing on desktop but not on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273193/logo-change-of-my-magento-rwd-theme-which-is-showing-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobil)

The *Excerpt* for the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag is already about as clear as we can make it:

> Logo is a computer programming language, created mainly for the purposes of education. If you're referencing logos in the sense of "corporate logos", please use the tag graphical-logo instead.

So, in the absence of any other options, and in the face of an incessant Chinese-water-torture-style drip of graphical-logo questions, I recommend that we take the undesirable step of renaming the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag to [logo-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-language) and finally put a stop to its misuse.

It seems like, even with its new name, it would still be easy enough for people to find.  It may not automatically recommend the newly-named tag just based on the word "logo" being used in the text of the question, but a simple search would find it.  I'm quite certain that there's no auto-code-formatting for the existing [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag that we need to worry about.  I know there's a chance that someone might recreate the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag at some point in the future, but I doubt the likelihood of it.  I'm willing to bet that if there's already a [logo-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-language) tag and a [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo) tag, that people will just use the appropriate one and no one will think to create a new one that's just called [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo).

I'm willing to do the work to create the new tag and edit all the old questions to point to it (there's only 39 legitimate logo questions, after-all), but I wanted to make sure that I had community-support before doing so.

Comment: I wonder why the posts remembers me "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is."

Comment: Are any of the non-language logo-questions on-topic, respectively does tagging them [tag:graphical-logo] actually categorize them in a relevant way? Should all but [tag:logo-language] die? Because it reads like those other tags were only created to redirect mistagged questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator.  In my opinion, yes.  I don't think the [tag:graphical-logo] tag would serve any legitimate purpose, except, I suppose, to discourage people from creating a plain [tag:logo] tag in the future.  I think that tag is useless which is why, in my clean-up efforts, I haven't bothered re-tagging the questions.  I've just been removing the [tag:logo] tag altogether.  I do think that it does make sense to keep it, though, just as a placeholder, to stop people from re-making a [tag:logo] tag.

Comment: Part of the trouble here is that Logo the language is best known for the accompanying turtle graphics.  If I hadn't read the wiki for graphical-logo, I would have assumed it was reserved for questions about turtle graphics in Logo as distinct from pure-language questions.

Comment: Since there are so few Logo language questions, maybe the tag should be "turtle-based-languages".  I like turtles.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler there is already a tag for [tag:turtle-graphics], which is technically more broad, since it's just a style of graphics which can be accomplished with any number of different languages/libraries/tools.  Besides, Logo is a full-featured language which can, and is, used for more than simply for turtle-graphics.

Comment: There's a similar problem on the [logos] tag, where Logos is an Objective-C preprocessor and people use it for graphical logos. It's much more minor though -- I've been able to stay on top of it myself.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I wonder if logo-lang might be nicer than logo-language? There are a lot of programming languages that have been using "xlang" lately, such as Go with golang.org. Is there a precedent for a `-language` suffix on tags? Is it the standard to spell it out in full? (I don't have a strong opinion, though; admittedly, I'm just bikeshedding, here.)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Ha!  That'll teach me to joke.  There are more programming niches than are dreamt of in my philosophy.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Did you have some reason for marking this as a duplicate?  I specifically mentioned that other question in my own question and discussed how the situation has evolved since then.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks for mentioning that.  See the update on my answer...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes.  That sounds like the best option available.

*I have posted this answer just so I can see a tally of people who support the proposal.  If you have any concerns or arguments against it, please post it as another answer.*

### Update

Based on the overwhelming unanimous support, I have decided to move ahead with this transition as described.  Based on David Conrad's suggestion, I will call the new tag [logo-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-lang) rather than [logo-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-language) since there is more of a precedent for "-lang" than there is for "-language" (see [julia-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-lang) and [slim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim-lang) as examples).  My plan is to:

1. Create a new tag called [logo-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-lang)
2. Copy the tag wiki from [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) to [logo-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-lang), adding a link to this post for reference
3. Re-tag all [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) questions with [logo-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo-lang)
4. Leave the existing [graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-logo) tag alone, but modify its wiki to explain its reason for existence with a link to this post.

Let the wild rumpus start!

### Upate 2

I have performed the steps outlined above, but the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag has not yet disappeared.  I suspect the reason is because of the following locked question:

- [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)

The question is tagged with the old [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag, but since it's closed and locked, I can't edit it to fix the tag.  This will, presumably, require moderator intervention.  I am flagging this answer in hopes that a moderator will be willing to help.

### Update 3

A moderator has kindly re-tagged that last question and the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag is now officially gone.  Unless the community changes its mind about it, if anyone sees the [logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logo) tag re-emerge in the future, please remove it by re-tagging the offending questions as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> There's typically only about one legitimate logo-language question per month

Since the elimination of the `logo` tag over a year ago, I see that there has been only one question tagged `logo-lang`.  Any thoughts on whether this is considered a success or a failure?

Comment: I've had the same concern.  There was actually one other question, just yesterday, but it was deleted by the OP shortly after it was posted.  The change has definitely been effective in terms of stopping incorrect usage of the tag.  But I do wonder if it has, in the process, discouraged new posts.  I would think that, if someone couldn't find the tag, they would have simply posted their question under a different tag or a new one, but that doesn't seem to have been happening.  So I'm inclined to think that interest in the language just happened to be particularly high a year ago.

Comment: I suspect that, at the time, there was an introductory programming class somewhere in the world which was using Logo, and many of the students in that class were using SO to ask for help with their class work.  Once that class ended (or the teacher discovered what was happening), the activity on the tag dropped.