# Different name for "basic" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Is there a way that the [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag could be renamed so people don't think it is meant for beginner questions? [I edited one post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39939311/revisions) and afterwards [I looked for other similar misuses of the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) and it looked to me like there were quite a few. Is there a way that the tag could be renamed so that it is obvious it refers to the family of programming languages and not the complexity of the question material, like `basic-family` or something similar? Or is this less of a problem than my small sample size has led me to believe?

## EDIT

Since posting this I have been occasionally glancing at the [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag and have frequently found misuses. Here is an incomplete list of the posts I have personally edited:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41686827/3
2. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41786467/2
3. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42181150/3
4. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42177126/3
5. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42447546/4
6. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42462692/3
7. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42460704/3
8. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42464726/2
9. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42497819/3
10. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42005686/4
11. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42681471/3
12. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42671218/2

This feels a little absurd considering there are a total of 513 [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) questions as of this edit, and considering the incomplete list of edits above would put me in the [top ten all time users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/basic/topusers) for the tag with 24 points if removing misuses counted towards that metric. Had someone answered each of these questions instead of removing the tags, they would be at least at the #2 all time answerer for [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) without answering a *single* question about any basic family language.

Comment: I spotted one question that was about "Python basics" where it was *totally* irrelevant. However, the remaining seems a mixed bag of BASIC dialects. Or unmentioned; [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38226520/2564301), for example, needs a version/dialect added. It's basically a mess.

Comment: Ambiguous tags are always worth discussing. I question I have is basic able to stand on its own anymore as a distinct tag? Seems most of the language tags that are part of the basic family are able to stand I their own now

Comment: What about [tag:Dartmouth-basic]....

Comment: @RadLexus I guess "quite a few" may have been an exaggeration. Nice on "basically" a mess.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285335/proposal-to-rename-logo-tag-to-logo-language?rq=1) looks like a very similar case

Comment: I suggest we rename it to `basic-lang` a la `julia-lang`.

Comment: Another example: [processing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286694/rename-processing-to-processing-language-or-similar) ...

Comment: As I understand it Basic is much like Lisp in that a single language hasn't actually existed for decades, making the term itself less useful for answering most questions... we should probably avoid anything that encourages users to tag questions with a nonexistent language (unless they actually have a question about the family tree) and instead promote tagging for specific dialects.

Comment: While I haven't actually done any specific checking and tallying, I have the feeling that I'm seeing more questions that misuse this tag to refer to "not very difficult; fundamentally easy concept; not advanced programming; etc." than to refer to "a member of the family of languages designated as dialects of Beginners All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code".

Comment: This question seems to have gone quiet, yet the issue still obtains. I suggest that this tag be renamed/redesignated [basic-language], or, alternatively, destroyed completely in favor of specific dialect tags, e.g., [visual-basic]. [vb.net], [gw-basic], [qbasic], etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is still an issue!

[basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) is still frequently being used for beginner level questions.

**All Time Statistics**:

To put in perspective how big of an issue this is I've adapted an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588491/tag-removal-stats?TagName=basic) to give an idea of how many times [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) is needing to be removed from questions. ([The complete list of edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588618/list-of-edits-that-remove-tag?TagName=basic))

It turns out that this tag was removed from 3879 of the 4394 total posts available in SEDE that started with the tag [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic)! That's **88.279 %** of posts that start with this tag end up having it removed.

**Last 120 Days**

If we look just at recent statistics ([The past 120 days](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588626/tag-removal-stats-with-creationdate-filter?TagName=basic&days=120)) the tag [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) was removed from 59 of the 63 posts that started with it; that's a **93.651 %** removal rate. ([List of edits for the last 120 days](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588627/list-of-edits-that-remove-tag-with-creationdate-filter?TagName=basic&days=120))

These edits are taking a significant amount of curator time and effort for a tag which is almost exclusively being used incorrectly.

---

Note: The actual amounts may be different as deleted posts are purged from the SEDE and are not considered.

Answer (score 2):

I updated the tag wiki excerpt to clarify what the tag is *not* meant to be used for. I don't know why no one had ever done this before.

It now reads:

> For questions about the BASIC (Beginner’s All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) programming language. DO NOT USE TO INDICATE YOUR QUESTION IS SIMPLE!

And, as you can see, that all fits into the tag picker:

[image]

Let's see how this works, if at all.

I cannot come up with any alternate names for the tag that I think are reasonable. [basic-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic-language) is annoying, redundant, and likely doesn't even help clarify things: users may well think that it's for questions that are about simple language constructs or written using simple language.

Comment: "I don't know why no one had ever done this before." Because ["\[p\]eople don't read the tag excerpts"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/). I'm actually surprised that you consider this a "solution".

Comment: I don't consider it a solution. I consider it "something". I don't really understand why you think your feature request, though, as we already do *precisely* that in the tag picker.

Comment: Simple, because that feature request doesn't target the tag picker, but the "suggested tags". Your "solution" wouldn't work if the system itself suggest the tag since the askers won't interact with the tag picker at all.